# Unclickable fill in Circle?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a mousemove event in my map and now I want to draw a circle with just the stroke line.

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#0000FF',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        radius: 100
    });
```

The problem is that the transparent fill center of that circle is still "capturing" the mouse event so it doesn't go to my Map mousemove listener.

Is there any way to really set the circle fill center to transparent as in: transparent color AND transparent dealing with mouse events?

In alternative, a way to easily propagate the event to the Map?

Comment: Does `clickable: false` help (not sure what that does for mouseover...). From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions) `clickable  boolean  Indicates whether this Circle handles mouse events. Defaults to true.` looks like it applies to all mouse events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clickable: false` to the CircleOptions passed to the constructor:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    clickable: false,
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    radius: 100
});
```